# 1 div inside another div change both background color hover

Tags: html, css, hover

the problem is in code have 2 div, when mouse go to first div background color is change and when go to second div both background color is change now i want when go to first div both background color is change!

```css
.aboutboth {
 width: 370px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.about-mohamad {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 170px;
 height: 230px;
 background: #666666;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 30px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear ;
 transition: all .5s linear ;
 position: relative;
}

.about-mohamad:hover {
 background: #e9e9e9;
}

.about-mohamad div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear ;
 transition: all .5s linear ;
}

.about-mohamad div:hover {
 background: #2d3030;
}

.about-mohamad span {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
}

.about-mohamad p {
 font-size: 10px;
}

.about-mohamad div img {
 margin-top: 25px;
}

.about-mohamad span#abouthovera {
    display:inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.about-mohamad:hover span#abouthovera {
    display:none;

}
.about-mohamad span#abouthoverb {
    display:none;
}
.about-mohamad:hover span#abouthoverb {
    display:inline;
    color: #666666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutboth">
    <div class="about-mohamad">
        <div><img src="http://rezaaria.com/1.png"></div>
  <span id="abouthovera">job</span>
  <span id="abouthoverb">name</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target first `<div>` hover to change both backgrounds.

```css
.aboutboth {
 width: 370px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.about-mohamad {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 170px;
 height: 230px;
 background: #666666;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 30px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear ;
 transition: all .5s linear ;
 position: relative;
}

.about-mohamad:hover {
 background: #e9e9e9;
}

.about-mohamad div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear ;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear ;
 transition: all .5s linear ;
}

.about-mohamad:hover div {
 background: #2d3030;
}

.about-mohamad span {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
}

.about-mohamad p {
 font-size: 10px;
}

.about-mohamad div img {
 margin-top: 25px;
}

.about-mohamad span#abouthovera {
    display:inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.about-mohamad:hover span#abouthovera {
    display:none;

}
.about-mohamad span#abouthoverb {
    display:none;
}
.about-mohamad:hover span#abouthoverb {
    display:inline;
    color: #666666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutboth">
    <div class="about-mohamad">
        <div><img src="http://rezaaria.com/1.png"></div>
  <span id="abouthovera">job</span>
  <span id="abouthoverb">name</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how you fix it ? could you explain please.

Comment: You just have to change `.about-mohamad div:hover` to `.about-mohamad:hover div`.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769432/position-fixed-with-100-height) could you help me to find solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.aboutboth:hover {
    background: #e9e9e9;
}
```

or

```
.aboutboth:hover  ~ .about-reza {
    background: #ccc
}
 .aboutboth:hover { 
    background: #ccc}
```

try this

Comment: This is an English site, if you write in another language, have the decency to translate it.

Comment: Ashkufaraz i need to change both background color for about-reza div and aboutboth! when mouse go on aboutboth div!

check this! http://jsfiddle.net/6t1u3wsr/ when mouse go on text "job" background color is change! but when mouse go on image about-reza div background color is change! how i can change both background color when mouse on go text!

Comment: about-mohamad and about-mohamad div change both background color after mouse hover on about-mohamad