# Position fixed with 100% height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want use 100% height for MAIN id but when I put it 100% height to main id, creativity class is placed on the main. when use pixel for main in different device its look different.

is there any solution to fix it ?

```css
#main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 675px;
}

.main {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url(/images/logo/logo.svg) center no-repeat #ffcc00;
}

.introduction {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #fcd803;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.introduction h1 {
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-top: 40px;
}

.introduction span img {
 width: 200px;
 padding-top: 30px;
}

.introduction div {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 21px;
}

.creativity {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 height: 320px;
 background: #fcd803;
}

.creativity-img {
 display: block;
 background: url('/images/ariadesk.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 background-position:bottom;
 width: 100%;
 height: 320px;
 position: absolute;
}

.creativity-img div {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 145px;
}

.creativity-img div h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 color: white;
 border: solid 2px #fff; 
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div class="main">
 <div class="logo"><h1>HUR</h1><br><span>studio</span></div>
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <a href="#introduction"><li>introduction</li></a>
   <a href="#ourwork"><li>work</li></a>
   <a href="#chooseus"><li>service</li></a>
   <a href="#client"><li>client</li></a>    
   <a href="#aboutus"><li>team</li></a>
   <a href="#contactus"><li>contact</li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="introduction" id="introduction">
 <h1>introduction</h1>
 <span>
        <img src="/images/icon/intro.svg" alt="">
 </span>
 <div><p>
  We are small team of super nerds and talented creatives. Create cutting-edge interfaces and visually stunnig media.<br>
  Experts in providing innovative Web Design, Graphic Design, Digital Imaging, Advertising and Branding service</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="creativity">
 <div class="creativity-img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind IE 8 and below, you can use `vh` (viewport-height) units:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLf2x1u1/1/)

Comment: I check it on BlackBerry browser its not work! I need best solution that work for all device!.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your ***position***

your #main is in the same level with .creativity

if you want the .main always on the top, just change your **.creativity** with  *z-index: 1*   **AND**   your  **.main**  with *z-index: 2*

You never set the  **.main**  index, and it always on the bottom layer.

Is it that case you want to?